# JMeter: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "Õ­"

Tags: java, apache, testing, jmeter, response

I am getting the following exception for a login page in Response Code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "Õ­"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sendPostData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1151)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:453)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:329)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what version of jmeter are you using ? could you show the request and response , if you cannot have it in jmeter try fiddler to display it to help debugging

Comment: It's JMeter 2.13, I have added Response in query. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't see it, are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, the exception in code snippet is Response code.

Comment: What I would like is the full response to see what part of it is breaking, thx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your are trying to decode an improperly encoded (or not at all encoded) value. See [Trying to decode % character in a parameter value JMeter fails with IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape(%) pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428421/trying-to-decode-character-in-a-parameter-value-jmeter-fails-with-illegalargum?rq=1) for more details.

If your are unfamiliar with encoding of query data, I suggest to firstly read about it.